# Is there an optimal sampling algorithm to determine the group with highest mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose i have N types of flowers and I want to find which flower people find the most beautiful. Each day, I have a new judge come in to rate (from 0 to 1) a flower of my choice. I have M>>N days to decide estimate which flower is the most beautiful.

If I let each flower be judged the same number of times, then in the end, the MLE estimate for the most beautiful flower would be the flower with the highest average rating.

However, are there any superior algorithms to determining which flower to get the judges to rate if we're doing this in sequence? What if we changed the question to be: which flowers have beautifulness > 0.8?

I feel like there should be a way but Im also unsure how. Distribution wise, let us assume the rating of the flower follows a beta distribution.

EDIT:
I define a superior algorithm as one that, under the above assumptions, estimates the most beautiful flower, with lowest cross entropy loss. Or replace cross entropy with something similar if it leads to a mathematically simpler solution.

Comment: Define "superior."

Comment: Good point. I define a superior algorithm as one that, under the above assumptions, estimates the most beautiful flower, with lowest cross entropy loss. Or replace cross entropy with something similar if it leads to a mathematically simpler solution.

Comment: The maximum-likelihood estimator for the parameters of a beta distribution are well known:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Maximum_likelihood

Comment: You can get $\gg$ using `\gg`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am familiar with Bayesian statistics, but Im talking before the inference stage when we're at the data collection stage if we can do a better job than just uniform sampling from the classes.

Comment: See best arm identification in multi-armed bandits http://sbubeck.com/COLT10_ABM.pdf